# get "Request Payload" in asp.net core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik-grid, .net-5, remote-validation

on the client side, I do

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/emplacements/keyexist',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

However the values in the action method are always 'null'

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult KeyExist(
    string nom,            //[Bind(Prefix = nameof(EmplacementDTO.Nom))],
    int id                 //[Bind(Prefix = nameof(EmplacementDTO.Id))]
)
{
    // nom == null
    // id == 0
```

[image]
how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first make a model for your payload like below.

```
public class MyPayload
{
    public string Nom{ get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and inside your controller `Action` method

```
public IActionResult KeyExist([FromBody] MyPayload payload)
```

`[FromBody]` will automatically map the request body if property names are matched.

and your `ajax` call has another issue that you sending the `Id` as `string` but the `Controller` expect an `int`

Comment: As this is json, if he sends `14` or `"14"`, that will have the same effect. If OP declares the bound parameter as int, it will be parsed to int during parameter binding.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues you are right but in some cases the binding will fail.